ValueError: Layer "dense_2" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors
i cant load my model it keep saying error
ValueError: Layer "dense_2" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1280), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_2896>, <KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 1280), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_2897>]
here's my code
image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2
)

train_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=path_to_dataset,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    subset='training'
)

validation_dataset = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
    directory=path_to_dataset,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    subset='validation'
)

# Menentukan jumlah kelas (num_classes) berdasarkan jumlah subfolder dalam dataset
num_classes = len(train_dataset.class_indices)

from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet import MobileNet

# Load the MobileNet model
pre_trained_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                                                      include_top=False,
                                                      weights='imagenet')


pre_trained_model.summary()

# Print dataset information for debugging
print(f"Training dataset shape: {train_dataset.image_shape}")
print(f"Validation dataset shape: {validation_dataset.image_shape}")

pre_trained_model.trainable = False

# Menambahkan layer kustom di atas model pre-trained
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    pre_trained_model,
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax') 
])

# Compile model
#from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

 batch=40
 history = model.fit(train_dataset,
               validation_data=validation_dataset,
               epochs=20,
               steps_per_epoch = train_dataset.samples//batch,
               validation_steps = validation_dataset.samples//batch,
               verbose = 1
           )

# Load the model
model_save_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Machine Learning/saved_models/model_plastik.h5'

# Load the model, ensuring it's compiled if needed
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_save_path) 

# Now you can modify the loaded model if necessary
# For example, if you want to extract a sub-model:
input_layer_index = 0  # Replace with the actual index
dense_2_index = 3  # Replace with the actual index
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=loaded_model.layers[input_layer_index].input, 
                                     outputs=loaded_model.layers[dense_2_index].output)

# Check the configuration of the loaded model
for i, layer in enumerate(loaded_model.layers):
    print(f"Layer {i}: {layer.name} - Input shape: {layer.input_shape} - Output Shape: {layer.output_shape}")

print("Revised model loaded successfully.")

i try to load model and i expect it loaded to test

Had the same issue, just try implementing the same architecture with Functional API and it'll work.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I encountered the same issue. In my case, the problem was caused by a mismatch between the TensorFlow versions used to save and load the model. Specifically, I trained and saved the model using TensorFlow 3.16, but I attempted to load it in a virtual environment with TensorFlow 3.18.
This version mismatch caused compatibility issues, which led to this error:
ValueError: Layer 'dense' expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors.
So I created a new virtual environment with TensorFlow 3.16 (the same version used to train and save the model). After loading the model in this environment, everything worked perfectly.
